# How to access a property in JSON from API request and display in React?

Tags: reactjs, json, django-rest-framework, axios

**Background**

I am currently trying to access the second property of a JSON file below named 'year_level'. I am doing this so that I can pass the data into an array and later display it in a react component for an autocomplete field. However, every time I try to write in the field, it crashes and gives me errors which do not really help me.

**JSON**

```
[{'prog_id': 'CDE', 'year_level': None}, {'prog_id': 'DDS1', 'year_level': '1'}, {'prog_id': 'DDS2', 'year_level': '2'}, {'prog_id': 'DDS3', 'year_level': '3'}]
```

**Relevant Code**

API request below that requires a join on 'prog_id' to access 'year_level':

```html
@api_view(["GET"])
def retrieve_prog_ids(request):
    progs = Event.objects.select_related('prog_id').values('prog_id').annotate(year_level=F('prog_id__year_level')).distinct()
    list = []
    for i in progs:
        list.append(i)

    print(list)
    return JsonResponse(list, safe = False)
```

axios request to access data in frontend:

```html
await axios({
            method: "get",
            url: "/events/prog-id/",
        })
            .then((res) => this.handleProgData(res.data))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

tried using a handler to access the data from api request and get the 'year_level':

```html
//Pushes year_levels into an array
    handleProgData(prog_data) {
        var programs = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < prog_data.length; i++) {
            programs.push(prog_data[i].year_level); //need 'year_level'
        }

        console.log(programs);
        this.setState({ programs });
    }
```

**Errors**

```html
utils.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'label') //...1st error

The above error occurred in the <AutoComplete> component: //... 2nd error

utils.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'label') //...3rd error
```

Please let me know as to why it is crashing every time I type in the autocomplete field. I'm thinking it is not correctly accessing 'year_level' but I could be wrong. Thank you in advance!